# Android Firebase Change Multiple Value

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Let's say I have a below database structure in Firebase Database.

```
   {
        "items": {
            "1": {
                "subitems": {
                    "2":"true",
                    "3":"false",
                    "4":"true"
                }
            },
            "2": {
                "subitems": {
                    "1":"false",
                    "4":"false",
                    "5":"true"
                }
            },
            "3": {
                "subitems": {
                    "6":"false",
                    "1":"false",
                    "7":"true"
                }
            }
        }
     }
```

I'd like to change all values of subitems which their keys equal to `"1"`.
As you can see, for 2nd and 3rd items' subitems keys are `1` and values are `false`.
How can I change these two items values as `true`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To solve this, please use the following code:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference itemsRef = rootRef.child("items");
ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            ds.child("subitems").child("1").getRef().setValue("true");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
};
itemsRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);
```

Comment: You are great!! To be honest, I'm still very bad on FireBase NoSQL and don't understand lots of things but you saved my life for the second time today. Many thanks mate!